# How to detect Android Go?

Tags: android, permissions, android-10.0, android-go

Is there any way to detect that device is running Android Go edition? Need to determine if device is capable of providing `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` since *API 29*.

According the reference, `Settings.canDrawOverlays(Context context)` will always return false on *API 29 Go*. Without knowing if the system is possible to give access to `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` it's hard to work around the case.

Comment: Well try to use that window and catch the exception.

Comment: @blackapps, how will it help me? The result will be the same for cases if the app runs on Android Q Go and if a user can allow SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW, but didn't that.

Comment: That i didnt know. Well it was just a suggestion...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
am.isLowRamDevice();
```

The following code is available in `ActivityManager.java`

```java
    /**
     * Returns true if this is a low-RAM device.  Exactly whether a device is low-RAM
     * is ultimately up to the device configuration, but currently it generally means
     * something with 1GB or less of RAM.  This is mostly intended to be used by apps
     * to determine whether they should turn off certain features that require more RAM.
     */
    public boolean isLowRamDevice() {
        return isLowRamDeviceStatic();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, will try! Possibly, do you know any way to emulate an Android Go device, also?

Comment: I tried setting an emulator to 1GB of ram, and `am.isLowRamDevice()` returned `false`, which is interesting.

Comment: And Orange, there are no Android Go emulators available yet, unfortunately

Comment: It doesn't seem the documentation is explicit that all Android Go devices are also  isLowRamDevice() == true.  Although I know of at least one that is.  Anyone find any evidence of this?

Answer (score 4):

You can refer to the implementation of the Android 11 source code.
It only uses `ActivityManager.isLowRamDevice()` to check if the `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission is available.

**packages\apps\Settings\src\com\android\settings\Utils.java**

```
/**
 * Returns true if SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission is available.
 * Starting from Q, SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW is disabled on low ram phones.
 */
public static boolean isSystemAlertWindowEnabled(Context context) {
    // SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW is disabled on on low ram devices starting from Q
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    return !(am.isLowRamDevice() && (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply query `PackageManager` to check if one of the Android GO preloaded apps is installed, as they have different package names.
For example:

Gmail Go package name: "com.google.android.gm.lite"

Regular Gmail package name: "com.google.android.gm"

```
fun isGoDevice(): Boolean {
    val GMAIL_GO_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.google.android.gm.lite"
    val packageManager = context.getPackageManager()
    return try {
        packageManager.getPackageInfo(GMAIL_GO_PACKAGE_NAME, 0)
        true
    } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
        false
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a foolproof method though, not all Android Go devices necessarily have the "Go version" of the system apps. The user may also have uninstalled the Gmail app, triggering a false negative.